# Position Sticky In React. Like the one on official facebook page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sticky

How to make the div container stick once it reach the top of the view port. I tried it with
`position: sticky; top: 0` it only for the top div once the second div moved the div with sticky position also moved. Below s the sudo code.

```
parent  div ---->
            it has two divs(flexed [1st, 2nd]) -----> 
                    Div 1st    Div 2nd
                 |-----------|----------|
                 |  Div 1    |          |
                 |           |    I     |
                 |  Div2     |    N     |
                 |           |    F     |  <<<<<< Infinite  Scroll
 Sticky  >>>>>>> |  Div3     |    I     |
 To the Top      |           |    N     |
         >>>>>>> |  Div4     |    I     |
                 |           |    T     |
                 |           |    e     |
                 |           |          |
                 |           |          |
                 |           |          |
                 |-----------|----------|
 
                The 1st div has 4 more divs(last two divs should be sticky)
                The 2nd div will have infilite scroll and will not be sticky
```

I want to acheive the same scroll behaviour when we visit the our profile page on facebook.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property `position: fixed` with `top` `left` `right` `bottom` properties instead of `postion: sticky`

**Div 2nd** should have `position: relative` and there should be another `div` inside **Div 2nd** that you want to be stick to a position and give the inner `div` the property of `position:fixed`

```css
.right-div{
 position: relative;
}
.stick-div{
position: fixed;
top: 3%;
background-color: black;
right: 13%;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-div"> left div <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>left div <br> <br> <br><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br> sdkasd</div>
<div class="right-div">
<div class="stick-div">
sticked to one place
</div>
</div>
```